# Use of deleted function error in qt C++ signals and slots

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

Could anyone please help me why I am getting this deleted function error even though I am passing parameters as pointer references (*&) ? This is a simple project working with multithreading in Qt, I just want to experiment sharing and modifying objects between parent and child threads. I am new in Qt, I am using Qt 5.9.2 with GCC 4.9.4 on Ubuntu Linux 14.04.

Thanks in advance.

```
===== Controller.hpp ===========
#pragma once

#include "data.hpp"

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>

class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread workerThread;
public:
    explicit Controller(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~Controller();

signals:
    void operate(Data*& data);

public slots:
    void handleResults(int idx);

private:
    Data _data;
};

===== Controller.cpp ===========
#include "controller.hpp"
#include "worker.hpp"

#include <QDebug>

Controller::Controller(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    Worker *worker = new Worker;
    worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
    connect(&workerThread, &QThread::finished, worker, &QObject::deleteLater);
    connect(this, &Controller::operate, worker, &Worker::doWork);
    connect(worker, &Worker::resultReady, this, &Controller::handleResults);
    workerThread.start();

    emit operate(&_data);
}

Controller::~Controller()
{
    workerThread.quit();
    workerThread.wait();
}

void Controller::handleResults(int idx)
{
    qDebug() << _data.at(idx);
}

===== Worker.hpp ===========
#pragma once

#include "data.hpp"

#include <QObject>

class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Worker(QObject *parent = nullptr);

signals:
    void resultReady(int idx);

public slots:
    void doWork(Data*& data);
};

===== Worker.cpp ===========
#include "worker.hpp"

Worker::Worker(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
}

void Worker::doWork(Data*& data)
{
    data->insertVal(10);
    emit resultReady(data->getSize());
}

===== Data.hpp ===========
#pragma once

#include <QObject>
#include <QVector>

class Data : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Data(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    void insertVal(int i);
    int getSize() const { return _intVec.size(); }

private:
    QVector<int*> _intVec;
};

===== Data.cpp ===========
#include <QDebug>

#include "data.hpp"

Data::Data(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
}

void Data::insertVal(int i)
{
    _intVec << &i;
    qDebug() << "Data inserted: " << i;
}

===== main.cpp ===========
#include "controller.hpp"
#include "data.hpp"

#include <QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qRegisterMetaType<Data>("Data");

    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Controller con;
    return a.exec();
}
```

I am getting these errors:

```
/home/raze/Qt/5.9.2/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qmetatype.h:765: error: use of deleted function ‘Data::Data(const Data&)’
             return new (where) T(*static_cast<const T*>(t));

/home/raze/Qt/5.9.2/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qobject.h:454: error: ‘QObject::QObject(const QObject&)’ is private
     Q_DISABLE_COPY(QObject)
                    ^
                                                           ^
/home/raze/Documents/Qt_projects/PracThread/data.hpp:6: error: within this context
 class Data : public QObject
       ^

/home/raze/Documents/Qt_projects/PracThread/data.hpp:6: error: use of deleted function ‘QObject::QObject(const QObject&)’
```

Comment: you should pass QObject by pointer , QObject `Data` through Worker and Controller class , you may use QSharedPointer to pass them all together and QObject class is not copyable and you can't pass it by value

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I didn't understand your suggestion properly, I am passing my Data class as *&, it shouldn't invoke copy constructors, and I don't want to include copy constructor for my QObject data type. Could you please elaborate, possible a sample line of code would be more helpful since I am quite new in C++ and Qt.

Comment: Ok I will provide a sample wait a moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you change `void operate(Data*& data);` to `void operate(Data*  data);`
in Controller class and change  `void doWork(Data*& data);` to `void doWork(Data* data);` in  worker class your code compiles well But from my comment Read [How Qt Signals and Slots Work](https://woboq.com/blog/how-qt-signals-slots-work.html) and [Effective Threading Using Qt](https://john.nachtimwald.com/2015/05/02/effective-threading-using-qt/) this articles looks good for all new to Qt/C++.

**Edit:**

from @altaf comments : To clarify, the root of the problem was cause by `qRegisterMetaType<Data>("Data");` in my main.cpp file. Data should be passed by pointers through signals and slots, so it should be registered as, something like `qRegisterMetaType<*Data>("pData");` All signals and slots should take the arguments as Data* pData

Comment: I have just changed it but getting the same error. Thanks for the links, going to read it.

Comment: I'm using gcc (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3) 7.2.0 as compiler an compiled code well. What's your compiler and if I could reproduce your problem off course, I would help you. I hope help you, thanks.

Comment: Qt 5.9.2 with GCC version 4.9.4 (Ubuntu 4.9.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 64 bit, I am using Qt community edition

Comment: @Altaf if you want I can send you whole sample project I have created, It compiles fine any way.

Comment: Please, my email: altaf.mahmud@gmail or you can post it here if you prefer, other people may get help as well. Thank you.

Comment: To clarify, the root of the problem was cause by qRegisterMetaType<Data>("Data");
in my main.cpp file. Data should be passed by pointers through signals and slots, so it should be registered as, something like qRegisterMetaType<*Data>("pData");
All signals and slots should take the arguments as Data* pData.
Thanks.